# update_option does not work in this scenario - how do I fix?

Tags: admin-menu, oop, options

I am attempting to use `update_option` to add or update an option.

I have created a test below which creates a settings page and when loaded it runs my `awd_do_sync` function, but the option does not get added or updated - why is this happening and what is the fix?

```
class MyClass {

    public function __construct() {

        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this, 'awd_settings' ) );

    }

    public function awd_settings() {

        add_submenu_page(
            'options-general.php',
            'AWD Settings',
            'AWD',
            'manage_options',
            'awd-settings',
            array( $this, 'awd_settings_page' )
        );

    }

    public function awd_settings_page() {

        $this->awd_do_sync();

    }

    public function awd_do_sync() {

        $log = 'test';

        update_option( 'awd_log', $log );

    }   

}

$go = new MyClass();
```

**SOLVED:**

I realised this was occurring because in my code, $log was a huge amount of text, therefore it appears there is a limit to what you can store in an option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I realised this was occurring because in my code, $log was a huge amount of text, therefore it appears there is a limit to what you can store in an option.